# Which special methods bypasses __getattribute__ in Python?

Tags: python, magic-methods

> In addition to bypassing any instance attributes in the interest of correctness, implicit special method lookup generally also bypasses the `__getattribute__()` method even of the object’s metaclass.

[The docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-special-lookup) mention special methods such as `__hash__`, `__repr__` and `__len__`, and I know from experience it also includes `__iter__` for Python 2.7.

To quote [an answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11360083/254704):

> "Magic `__methods__()` are treated specially: They are internally assigned to "slots" in the type data structure to speed up their look-up, and they are only looked up in these slots."

In a quest to improve my answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709194/the-proper-way-of-completely-overriding-attribute-access-in-python), I need to know: Which methods, specifically, are we talking about?

Comment: Which methods are assigned to slots?

Comment: I think every method listed [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#specialnames). Anyway take into account that this does only apply if you call the method using "its syntax". For example `a+5` will not call `__getattribute__`, while `a.__add__(5)` *will* call it.
Fundamentally `__getattribute__` is called whenever you use the dot(`.`) to access an attribute.

Comment: @Bakuriu: Very informative, thank you.

Comment: @Bakuriu: can you put your comments in an answer please? Also, note that Python 3 behaves the same as you described, but has a much clearer documentation on this point.

Comment: @Bakuriu `__getattribute__` also have used with `hasattr(obj, method)` method

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry You're right! I've added a note on this in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find an answer in the python3 [documentation](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__getattribute__#object.__getattribute__) for `object.__getattribute__`, which states:

> Called unconditionally to implement attribute accesses for instances of the class. If the class also defines `__getattr__()`, the
>   latter will not be called unless `__getattribute__()` either calls it
>   explicitly or raises an AttributeError. This method should return the
>   (computed) attribute value or raise an AttributeError exception. In
>   order to avoid infinite recursion in this method, its implementation
>   should always call the base class method with the same name to access
>   any attributes it needs, for example, object.`__getattribute__(self,
>   name)`.
>
> **Note**
>
> This method may still be bypassed when looking up special methods as the result of implicit invocation via language syntax or built-in
>   functions. See Special method lookup.

also [this](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__getattribute__#special-lookup) page explains exactly how this "machinery" works. Fundamentally `__getattribute__` is called only when you access an attribute with the `.`(dot) operator(and also by `hasattr` as Zagorulkin pointed out).

Note that the page does not specify which special methods are implicitly looked up, so I deem that this hold for all of them(which you may find [here](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__getattribute__#specialnames).

Comment: did you actually check? i did check on 2.7.9 and it seems the docs aren't quite right on that.

Answer (score 2):

Checked in 2.7.9

Couldn't find any way to bypass the call to `__getattribute__`, with any of the magical methods that are found on `object` or `type`:

```
# Preparation step: did this from the console
# magics = set(dir(object) + dir(type))
# got 38 names, for each of the names, wrote a.<that_name> to a file
# Ended up with this:

a.__module__
a.__base__
#...
```

Put this at the beginning of that file, which i renamed into a proper python module (asdf.py)

```
global_counter = 0

class Counter(object):
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        # this will count how many times the method was called
        global global_counter
        global_counter += 1
        return super(Counter, self).__getattribute__(name)

a = Counter()
# after this comes the list of 38 attribute accessess
a.__module__
#...
a.__repr__
#...

print global_counter  # you're not gonna like it... it printer 38
```

Then i also tried to get each of those names by `getattr` and `hasattr` -> same result. `__getattribute__` was called every time.

So if anyone has other ideas... I was too lazy to look inside C code for this, but I'm sure the answer lies somewhere there.

So either there's something that i'm not getting right, or the docs are lying.

Comment: If I remember correctly, my question was about `repr(a)` as opposed to `a.__repr__()`. It's been a while since I was into this stuff, but I'm guessing you get the getattribute version because you look up attributes, whereas the built-in methods we are talking about (the global `repr`, not `__repr__`) bypasses the existance of `__repr__`.

Comment: Override `__getattribute__` to issue a print whenever it's called and then do: `Counter('a') + Counter('a')` and see that it doesn't print anything. Because it's bypassing the standard name look up and hitting `Counter.__dict__['__add__']` directly or some such silly thing in the name of optimization.

Answer (score -1):

`super().method` will also bypass `__getattribute__`. This atrocious code will run just fine (Python 3.11).

```py
class Base:
    def print(self):
        print("whatever")

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        raise Exception("Don't access this with a dot!")


class Sub(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super().print()

a = Sub()
# prints 'whatever'
a.print()
# Exception Don't access this with a dot!
```