# Python object proxying: how to access proxy

Tags: python, proxy-classes

I found [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/496741-object-proxying/) recipe to create a proxy class. I've used it to wrap a custom object and would like to overload certain properties and also attach new attributes to the proxy. However, when I call any method on the proxy (from within the proxy class), I end up being delegated to the wrappee which is not what I want.

Is there any way of accessing or storing a reference to the proxy?

Here's some code (untested) to demonstrate the problem.

```
class MyObject(object):
  @property
  def value(self):
    return 42

class MyObjectProxy(Proxy): # see the link above
  def __getattribute__(self, attr):
    # the problem is that `self` refers to the proxied 
    # object and thus this throws an AttributeError. How 
    # can I reference MyObjectProxy.another_value()?
    if attr == 'value':  return self.another_value() # return method or attribute, doesn't matter (same effect)
    return super(MyObjectProxy, self).__getattribute__(attr)

  def another_value(self):
    return 21

o = MyObject()
p = MyObjectProxy(o)
print o.value
print p.value
```

In a sense my problem is that the proxy works too good, hiding all its own methods/attributes and posing itself as the proxied object (which is what it should do)...

**Update**

Based on the comments below, I changed `__getattribute__` to this:

```
def __getattribute__(self, attr):
    try:
        return object.__getattribute__(self, attr)
    except AttributeError:
        return super(MyObjectProxy, self).__getattribute__(attr)
```

This seems to do the trick for now, but it would be better to add this directly to the `Proxy` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that your code goes wrong is the **loop** in `__getattribute__`. You want to override `__getattribute__` so you can reach certain properties in the proxy class itself. But let's see.

When you call `p.value` the `__getattribute__` is called. Then it comes here `if attr == 'value':  return self.another_value()`. Here we need to call `another_value` so we enter `__getattribute__` again.

This time we comes here `return super(MyObjectProxy, self).__getattribute__(attr)`. We call the `Proxy`'s `__getattribute__`, and it tries to fetch `another_value` in `Myobject`. So the exceptions occur.

You can see from the traceback that we finally goes to `return super(MyObjectProxy, self).__getattribute__(attr)` that should not go to.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "proxytest.py", line 22, in <module>
    print p.value
  File "proxytest.py", line 13, in __getattribute__
    if attr == 'value':  return self.another_value() # return method or attribute, doesn't matter (same effect)
  File "proxytest.py", line 14, in __getattribute__
    return super(MyObjectProxy, self).__getattribute__(attr)
  File "/home/hugh/m/tspace/proxy.py", line 10, in __getattribute__
    return getattr(object.__getattribute__(self, "_obj"), name)
AttributeError: 'MyObject' object has no attribute 'another_value'
```

**edit:**
Change the line of code `if attr == 'value': return self.another_value()` to `if attr == 'value':  return object.__getattribute__(self, 'another_value')()`.

Comment: Thanks for reproducing and confirming the above, @zhangyangyu. Any suggestions on how to get the desired behaviour?

Comment: I thought I had tried that before, but I must have made a mistake. Your solutions works fine. I'll have a look at fixing the `proxy` class to look for its own attributes first before accessing the proxied one's.

Comment: Fixing the `Proxy` class directly seems like a bigger problem than I thought. I tried to call `hasattr(self, attr)` in `__getattribute__`, but this seems to end in an infinite loop (is `hasattr` really calling `__getattribute`?)

Comment: Yes. Read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12872695/which-special-methods-bypasses-getattribute-in-python).@orange

Comment: Nasty! I updated my question with your answer and what I found at the post you linked.